# How can I convert native PHP into query builder Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

How to convert from native php into query builder laravel

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = array(); 
    $sql_query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts))*1000 As ts, sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay FROM enginepoker_log.poker WHERE GROUP BY Date(ts) ORDER BY Date(ts) LIMIT 30 ";
```

and I already make query builder but still got an error. 
and this is the error

> (2/2) QueryException  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts), sum(pot +
>   p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4p' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts), sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot +
>   p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As
>   moneyInPlay from `enginepoker_log`.`poker` group by `Date(ts)` order
>   by `Date(ts)` asc)

this is query builder:

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
                                ->selectRaw("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts)")
                                ->selectRaw("sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
                                ->groupBy("Date(ts)")
                                ->orderBy("Date(ts)")
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();
```

this is in blade pages

```
@php
foreach ($statsMoneyInPlay as $key => $value) {
echo "[".$value[0].", ".$value[1]."],";
@endphp
```

Comment: Please add what you've tried to do so far. It should help us help you.

Comment: Ok, I already add in my question @JaimeRojas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're looking for should look a little more like this:

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
 ->select(
   DB::raw("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100) as timestamp"),
   DB::raw("SUM(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
 )
 ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(ts)"))
 ->orderByRaw("DATE(ts)")
 ->get()
 ->toArray();
```

In blade, you can access the elements by doing this:

```
foreach($statsMoneyInPlay as $stat) {
  echo "[" . $stat->timestamp . ", " . $stat->moneyInPlay . "]";
}
```

Comment: i still got error this is the error said (2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1583 Incorrect 
parameters in the call to native function 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' 
(SQL: select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as timestamp), 
SUM(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / 
count(*) As moneyInPlay from `enginepoker_log`.`poker` group by DATE(ts) order 
by DATE(ts))

Comment: That was most likely due to a misplaced parenthesis. I've updated the query,

Comment: thank you but I got some probelm when I access I get error like this Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\enginepoker2\storage\framework\views\10cbbd076bede57a96e59c43af0e1b9e022b4a69.php on line 115

Comment: The issue is not with the query anymore, but with the way you're handling the array. The correct thing to do would've been to close this question with this answer and ask a new one. Still, I'll update my answer to show you the correct way to handle it.